# How do I specify a chess symbol from Google Sans Symbol 2?

Tags: css, web-fonts, unicode

How do I have a web page in which most things are from Noto Sans Mono but some symbols, like the chess white bishop U+2657 (or ♗) comes from Noto Sans Symbol 2?

I tried going to the Noto Sans Symbol 2 web page here: https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Symbols+2/glyphs but the instructions for how to embed this font in a web page seem just to have to do with Noto Sans Mono. Aren't Noto Sans Symbol 2 and Noto Sans Mono different fonts? For one thing, Noto Sans Mono does not even have U+2657 does it?

Anyway, when I tried specifying that font family: font-family: 'Noto Sans Mono', monospace; as specified on the Google web page, the symbol was not found and defaulted (Chrome/Mac) to Menlo.

I am neither a web designer nor a font expert so please ask for further clarification if the information I am giving is insufficient.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Not sure I understand the problem. Have you actually selected the font?  The instructions clearly contain the reference to "Noto Sans Symbols 2". [see here](https://imgur.com/XMBYrCo)

Comment: It appears that the download instructions are different at different times and for different people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is more about coding than about graphic design, so it would probably be a better fit for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

I'll answer anyway because it has an element of graphic design in it.

To make the fonts available to your website, you could place them in a `fonts` folder in the root of your site. The simplest structure would look something like this:

```
\
  fonts
    NotoSansMono-Regular.ttf
    NotoSansSymbols2-Regular.ttf
  index.html
  style.css
```

In the `.css` file you can add the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: NotoSansMono;
  src: url("fonts/NotoSansMono-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: NotoSansSymbols2;
  src: url("fonts/NotoSansSymbols2-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

This imports the two fonts and makes them available for use in CSS rules.
Read more about the `@font-face` CSS at-rule [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).

Now you could make CSS rules like this:

```
p {
  font-family: NotoSansMono;
}

span.symbol {
  font-family: NotoSansSymbols2;
}
```

And test it with HTML markup like this:

```
<p>ABCDEFGH</p>
<p>ABCD♗FGH</p>
<p>ABCD<span class="symbol">♗</span>FGH</p>
```

The result would look like this:

[image]

Noto Sans Mono doesn't seem to have the `♗` character so without the `<span>` it renders with a symbol font chosen by the browser. But with the span it renders as Noto Sans Symbols 2 as expected.

I suspect you need this for some coding language, and it might be an issue that the `♗` character is wider than the characters of the monospaced Noto Sans Mono so the characters from different text lines won't line up.

I've searched a bit for a monospaced font that has the `♗` character, but without luck.

Comment: Thank you. I think I am getting closer to understanding some of this stuff.